# Error extracting tar.xz files on Linux

Tags: linux, centos, tar, xz

I have a bunch of tar.xz files I need to extract. I tried using the following command, but get errors when it tries to extract individual files.

```
tar -xJf file.tar.xz

tar: Example_path/and_file_name.config: Cannot open: Invalid argument
tar: Example_path/the_next_file.config: Cannot open: Invalid argument
```

The result is a directory full of empty files for every attempted extraction. I have tried both `-xJf` and `-xf` and get the same result. In case it matters, the files are located on a shared Windows storage server, and I am executing the command from the data directory using my Linux machine. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: what is your version of `tar`?

Comment: Check if the file is really compressed: `file file.tar.xz`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale It's tar 1.26

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes, the `file` command confirms that it is a compressed XZ file

Comment: @DavidK, have you try `xz -d file.tar.xz|tar tvf -` to test if the `tar` is OK?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you extract to a local folder? `tar -xJf file.tar.xz -C /tmp/`

Comment: @RomeoNinov I wasn't able to get that syntax to work. I am able to unzip and untar the files using 7-zip on a Windows machine though, so I know the files are good.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale That actually *did* work! So there must be some reason I can't extract completely to the network drive. If write permissions were blocked entirely, I would expect I wouldn't be able to create the directories and empty files though.

Comment: @DavidK, my mistake, the command should be: `xz -dc file.tar.xz|tar tvf -`

Comment: @DavidK This answer suggests that error can happen when there are jank characters in the file names: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349915/247007 . Maybe tar can create the files, but chokes when creating the actual data stream?

Comment: NTFS advanced permissions can also technically deny `modify` while allowing `create`, but that would be... pretty weird